# How to use a nested closure as the first argument to List::Util::reduce?

Tags: closures, perl

NB: the closure featured in this question is just a convenient example; the one I'm actually working with is substantially more complex than this.  IOW, please disregard the details of this closure; all that matters, AFAICT, is that it refers to lexical variables in the parent scope.

---

I want to redefine the sub `foo` below so that the first argument in the call to `List::Util::reduce` is replaced with a reference to a nested closure.

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use List::Util;

sub foo {
  my ( $x, $y ) = @_;
  return List::Util::reduce { $y->[ $b ]{ $x } ? $a + ( 1 << $b ) : $a } 0, 0 .. $#$y;
}
```

My first attempt was this:

```
sub foo {
  my ( $x, $y ) = @_;
  sub z {
    our ( $a, $b );
    return exists $y->[ $b ]{ $x } ? $a | ( 1 << $b ) : $a;
  }
  return List::Util::reduce \&z, 0, 0 .. $#{ $y };
}
```

...but this results in a warning saying that `Variable "$y" will not stay shared`.

I've seen this sort of error before, and the only way I know around it is to replace the nested `sub` definition with an anonymous sub assigned to a variable.  Therefore, I tried this instead:

```
sub foo {
  my ( $x, $y ) = @_;
  my $z = sub {
    our ( $a, $b );
    return exists $y->[ $b ]{ $x } ? $a | ( 1 << $b ) : $a;
  };
  return List::Util::reduce( $z, 0, 0 .. $#{ $y } );
}
```

Now the error says `Type of arg 1 to List::Util::reduce must be block or sub {} (not private variable)`.

This I really don't understand.  Why would passing a subref as the first argument to `reduce` not be supported?

---

PS: The following does work:

```
sub foo {
  my ( $x, $y ) = @_;
  my $z = sub {
    our ( $a, $b );
    return exists $y->[ $b ]{ $x } ? $a | ( 1 << $b ) : $a;
  };
  return List::Util::reduce { $z->( $a, $b ) } 0, 0 .. $#{ $y };
}
```

...but I really would like to know (a) what's wrong with using a subref as the first argument to `List::Util::reduce` (e.g. is there some technical impediment to supporting this variant?); and (b) is there a more direct approach (than `{ $z->( $a, $b ) }`) to passing to `List::Util::reduce` a nested closure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reduce` has a prototype of `&@`. That means calls must use one of the following syntax:

```
reduce BLOCK LIST
reduce sub BLOCK, LIST  # The first form is short for this.
reduce \&NAME, LIST
reduce \&$NAME, LIST    # Same as third form, but via reference (short form)
reduce \&BLOCK, LIST    # Same as third form, but via reference (long form)
```

You could use any of the following equivalent statements:

```
return reduce { exists $y->[ $b ]{ $x } ? $a | ( 1 << $b ) : $a } 0, 0 .. $#$y;
```

```
# Long way of writing the first.
return reduce(sub { exists $y->[ $b ]{ $x } ? $a | ( 1 << $b ) : $a }, 0, 0 .. $#$y);
```

```
my $z = sub { exists $y->[ $b ]{ $x } ? $a | ( 1 << $b ) : $a };
return reduce(\&$z, 0, 0 .. $#$y);
```

You also have the option of overriding the prototype.

```
my $z = sub { exists $y->[ $b ]{ $x } ? $a | ( 1 << $b ) : $a };
return &reduce($z, 0, 0 .. $#$y);
```

Comment: How to use the last form `reduce \&BLOCK, LIST` ? I tried the following: `perl -mList::Util -E 'say List::Util::reduce \&{ $a > $b ? $a : $b }, 1..10'` and I got segmentation fault.

Comment: The block is evaluated on the spot and must return a ref to a sub, such as `\&{ $z }`

Answer (score 4):

`List::Util::reduce` uses a Perl *prototype* which specifies a *compile-time* check on the parameters passed in a call. Passing a scalar variable that contains a subroutine reference cannot be verified at compile time so Perl disallows it

This is also the route to the the solution. It is usually considered bad practice to call a subroutine using an ampersand character `&` but in this case it will defeat the prototype checking, which is what is required

```
sub foo {

  my ( $x, $y ) = @_;

  my $z = sub {
    our ( $a, $b );
    return exists $y->[ $b ]{ $x } ? $a | ( 1 << $b ) : $a;
  };

  return &List::Util::reduce( $z, 0, 0 .. $#{ $y } ); # Defeat prototype
}
```

Note that this isn't possible in general, as a prototype can do such things as force an array or hash to be passed by reference, or force scalar context on an expression, and calling such a subroutine using `&` will disable these behaviours as well. But `reduce` has a prototype of `&@` which means a block or `sub { }` (the `sub` part is optional here) followed by a list of scalars, which is the normal behaviour for a subroutine without a prototype, so the only effect is to allow `$z` to be passed for the subroutine reference

Comment: How did you determine the prototype of `reduce`? I tried to determine it from the [source code](https://metacpan.org/source/PEVANS/Scalar-List-Utils-1.45/lib/List/Util.pm) at [metacpan.org](https://metacpan.org/) but it gives me no prototypes ( it just calls `XSLoader::load()` ).

Comment: @HåkonHægland: The module's coded in C so it's in [the XS file `ListUtil.xs`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/PEVANS/Scalar-List-Utils-1.45/ListUtil.xs) at line 369